# Cannot implicitly convert type 'User' to 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm facing an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'User' to 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser'` in ASP.NET MVC 4 application while using Custom Membership provider.

Here is my custom membership provider class and GetUser method which raising error.

```
public class InvoicingMembershipProvider : System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider
{
    private InvoiceDB db = new InvoiceDB();

    :::::::::::::

    public override System.Web.Security.MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Name == username).FirstOrDefault();
        return user;
    }

    ::::::::::::
}
```

Please let me know how to cast user object to MembershipUser object?

Answer (score 0):

```
public override System.Web.Security.MembershipUser  GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        System.Web.Security.MembershipUser user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Name == username).FirstOrDefault();
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: I still see Cannot implicitly convert type 'User' to 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' error

Comment: Could you explain your solution, you posted only code without explanations?